# How can I save a currently edited file from the command line?

Tags: bash, terminal

I like to take all notes in one .txt file and would like to write a bash script which adds the date on midnight to the end of the file automatically with a cronjob.

So the file should look something like this:

```
Monday 19/09/22
my really long notes
Tuesday 20/09/22
my other long notes
Thursday 21/09/22
```

Adding the date is not a problem but writing to a file that is open and not saved.

So my question is: How can I save an open file from the command line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `"my really long notes" > /path/to/open/file` works for you?

Comment: Do you mean that you use an editor to edit file.txt, and sometimes leaves it open and unsaved? And so, that you want to be able to add this line in the editor? If so, this is not at all a bash problem. It has to be solved by the editor. Since data are only in the editor memory. You have either to communicate with the editor, if it is open, to make it add the date (instead of adding it directly to the file). Or, at least, to parameter the editor to autosave / autoreload the file content, so that the cron's "echo" write in a uptodate file, and that the edited file reflect the date addition.

Comment: @chrslg I exactelly mean that. I edit the text file with Sublime. Now I enabled the autsave functionality and always on 2am in the morning I add the date line. Works for me quite smoothly. Thank you all for your responses.